# How do you "mix" colors as mentioned in the Material Design Guidelines?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, colors, material-design

The Material Design Guidelines mention mixing and adding shades of colors. Here are some examples I've come across:

From the [icon](https://material.google.com/style/icons.html#icons-product-icons) guidelines:

> **Tinted edge**
>   The top edge of a material element. *A tint is the mixture of a color with white*, which lightens the original color.
>
> **Shaded edge**
>   The bottom edge of a material element. *Shade is the mixture of a color with a darker hue*, which darkens the original color.

---

From the [button](https://material.google.com/components/buttons.html#buttons-button-types) guidelines:

> **Raised Light/Light theme**
>   Minimum width: 88dp
>   Height: 36dp
>   Corner radius: 2dp
>   Disabled text: 26% #000000
>   Disabled button: 12% #000000
>
> Focused:12% #000000 *shade over the color*

**Questions:**
How do you mix a color with another color?
How do you put a shade over a color?
Can I do any of this in AndroidStudio/programmatically?

Comment: I dont think this is the spot for this question since its more of a photoshop type of question

Comment: As far as the icon example you might be right, but the button color can be set programatically.

Comment: I'm sure there is some algorithm to mix two ARGB values if you are trying to do it programmatically

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking for an algorithm, then get an array of 4 ints, alpha, red,green,blue, for both colors, add them respectively, then find the maximum value of the new array, then do max_value/255, store that in a variable, and divide every number in the array by that. Hopefully I didn't screw up my paragraph.
Use BufferedImage to get the colors of the pixels, and then mix it with the color you want.

Example code:

```
public int mixColor(int color,int color2) {

    int red1=(color&0xff0000)>>>16,green1=(color&0xff00)>>>8,blue1=(color&0xff);
    int red2=(color2&0xff0000)>>>16,green2=(color2&0xff00)>>>8,blue2=(color2&0xff);

    int nred=red1+red2,ngreen=green1+green2,nblue=blue1+blue2;
    double maximum=Math.max(nred,Math.max(ngreen,nblue));
    double ratio=maxiumum/255;
    double totalRed=nred/ratio,totalGreen=ngreen/ratio,totalBlue=nblue/ratio;
    int result=(((int)totalRed<<16)|((int)totalGreen<<8)|((int)totalBlue));

    return result;

}
```

Then you can just write new Color(mixColor(color1,color2))` to get the desired answer.